# Como alterar o tamanho de fonte das opções do select?

Tags: html, css

Tenho um `select` no meu `form` mas não consigo alterar o tamanho de fonte das opções.

Veja imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como aumentar o tamanho da fonte da lista de opções? Pois já tentei `font-size` e nada funcionou.

**HTML**

```
<figure class="cx-fotos-portugal">

    <form>
    <select>
        <option selected="selected">Escolha a cidade</option>
        <option value="">Cascais</option>
        <option value="">Lisboa</option>
        <option value="">Porto</option>
    </select>
    </form>

    <img src="./fotos-portugal/foto-portugal-capitania-do-porto-cascais.jpg">

</figure>
```

**CSS**

```
figure.cx-fotos-portugal{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

figure.cx-fotos-portugal form{
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url("../imagens/ponto-transparente-seletor-principal.png");
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

figure.cx-fotos-portugal img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 550px;
}

figure.cx-fotos-portugal form select{
    font-size: 35px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #b9bdc1; 
    color: #797979; 
    height: 55px;
}

figure.cx-fotos-portugal form select option{
    font-size: 35px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #b9bdc1; 
    color: #797979; 
    height: 55px;
}
```

Comment: Tentou classificar o font-size como importante?  font-size: 35px !important;

Comment: `option { font-size:35px;}`?

Comment: Poderia adicionar o restante do `CSS`? [O seu código funcionou corretamente aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/8wt75wg0/)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode adicionar a tag `<optgroup>`

```css
optgroup { font-size:35px !important; }
```

```html
 <form>
        <select>
            <optgroup>
            <option selected="selected">Escolha a cidade</option> 
            <option value="">Cascais</option>
            <option value="">Lisboa</option>
            <option value="">Porto</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
    </form>
```

Comment: Editei porque, dei um vacilo e englobei o option selecionado também. Não há necessidade.

Comment: Aqui não fez efeito. Veja! `figure.cx-fotos-portugal form select optgroup{
    font-size: 35px;
}`

Comment: Também não funcionou para você. Clique para exibir a lista de opções, os nomes cascais, lisboa e porto estão com fonte menor.

Comment: Gladison, funcionou sim. Da uma olhada. https://jsfiddle.net/k2w1rzxs/

Comment: Existe algum `.css` feito por você ou importado por você que não permite você trabalhar direito. Para fins de experimento adicione o !important na frente do estilo que demonstrei.

Comment: Disponibilizei o executável aqui e também um jsfiddle. Em todos os casos o `option` sofre alteração de tamanho.